# List/Array of matrices in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to create the following expression in sympy:

[image: \sum_{k=0}^p \mathbf{M}\mathbf{A}^{(k)}\mathbf{U}]

`M`, `U` and `A^(k)` are square matrices of size `m`.

So far, I managed to do this for a given `p`:

```
import sympy

m = sympy.symbols('m', integer=True)
p = 3

A = [sympy.MatrixSymbol('A^({})'.format(k), m, m) for k in range(p)]
M = sympy.MatrixSymbol('M', m, m)
U = sympy.MatrixSymbol('U', m, m)

expr = M*A[0]*U
for k in range(1, p):
    expr += M*A[k]*U
expr
```

[image]

However, I do not want to set `p` to a fixed number. Instead I want `p` to be a symbol, just like `m`. How can this be achieved in sympy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way. For now, I managed to achieve what I want by defining `A` as a function rather than a list:

```
m, p, k = symbols('m, p, k')

M = sympy.MatrixSymbol('M', m, m)
U = sympy.MatrixSymbol('U', m, m)

class A(sympy.Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, k):
        return sympy.MatrixSymbol('A^({})'.format(k), m, m)

sympy.Sum(M * A(k) * U, (k, 1, p))
```